# Is it possible to search by commit hash in gitk?

Tags: git, gitk

By default the commit search box in gitk searches in various commit fields, but doesn't include the hash. This makes it hard to locate a particular commit, especially if you only have an abbreviated hash.

Are there any workarounds for this problem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can type the hash (abbreviation) into the box right underneath the list of commits, and then click the "Goto" button to the left of the box.

[image: Gitk UI]

Comment: Thanks, it works. I could have sworn I had tried it :)

Comment: You may want to clarify that one must actually start typing into the box for the "Goto:" button to appear!

Answer (score 6):

You can start gitk with the commit sha as an argument:

```
gitk abc123
```

This will make the said commit appear at the top, along with any previous commits. Any commits succeeding that commit will not be shown though.

Comment: Thanks, not bad. Any ideas about searching from inside gitk, though?

Comment: Actually, yes. I posted another answer.